# Get data from SmartCard UEC

Tags: c++, smartcard, apdu

I already asked a question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658283/c-getslotlisttokenpresent-pslotlist-pulcount-return-pulcount-0) about my SmartCard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_electronic_card), but I would like to know: is it possible to get a specific record from a smart card, knowing the pin code and where the record is located?

Map developed by ISO-7816, so the APDU-command must be based on the following scheme:

> [CLA] [INS] [P1] [P2] [Lc field] [Data field] [Le field]

How APDU-command should look like and what the library is better to use on C++/C#, if I need the data from the field 5F20?

P.s.: here is data from file sectors.ini:

> [Sector1_11]
>
> Icon = "IDENTIFICATION SECTOR"
>
> BlockDescr1 = "0 | 0 | The data block for sharing"
>
> BlockDescr2 = "0 | 0 | block public access to the PIN"
>
> DataDescr21 = "DF27 | 1 | 6 | 0,0,0 | 1 | SNILS"
>
> DataDescr22 = "DF2B | 4 | 8 | 0,0,0 | 1 | Number of MHI"
>
> DataDescr23 = "5F20 | 0 | 26 | 0,0,0 | 1 | Name"
>
> DataDescr24 = "DF23 | 0 | 100 | 0,0,0 | 1 | Address of the issuer"
>
> DataDescr25 = "5F2B | 4 | 4 | 0,0,0 | 1 | Born"
>
> DataDescr26 = "DF24 | 0 | 100 | 0,0,0 | 1 | Birthplace"
>
> DataDescr27 = "5F35 | 3 | 1 | 0,0,0 | 1 | Paul"
>
> DataDescr28 = "DF2D | 0 | 40 | 0,0,0 | 1 | Last"
>
> DataDescr29 = "DF2E | 0 | 40 | 0,0,0 | 1 | Name"
>
> DataDescr210 = "DF2F | 0 | 40 | 0,0,0 | 1 | Middle"

I only know that the third number indicates the amount of data in bytes.